# How to create bootstrap grid that is responsive in all devices

Tags: theming

I created a bootstrap grid views block with 4 columns. When I visit the page in mobile device, I see one column grid. When I visit the page in tablet device, I also see one column grid plus blank to the right.

[image]

[image]

How can I make it more responsive? I am also confused how it should behave in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What classes exactly did you use ?

The breakpoints used for the grid could be different depending of what device size you aim for your columns.
The smallest size handled by the BS grid is for devices with **< 768px width** by adding class `col-xs-*` (in Boostrap 3, for Bootstrap 4 it's up to [576px](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options)).
Typically this is for some tablets & almost all smartphones in portrait mode.

If you only want set classes for superior size, it will automatically be stacked on extra small devices.
For example, if you used `col-md-3` for each column, when the device width will worth < 768px, all the columns will be stacked each under the others (which is often wanted on small width regarding layouts).
But you can add `col-xs-6` too on each to have 50/50 columns on small devices.

See more Bootstrap documentation about the Bootstrap grid system : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: Using bootstrap 3  For the views block that I created, I gave these bootstrap classes to the block   col-md-10  col-sm-12  com-xs-12.  I have one views grid block with 4 columns. I am not sure how the 4 columns break into 3 col > 2 col > 1 col depending on sizes of screens.

Comment: Added one more image which shows the block classes that I gave to the views bootstrap grid block.